# Trouble converting Matlab numerical operators to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a problem converting this Matlab code to python. w2_A,w2_B and w2 plus the Tk[1] and Tk[2] get the same results as in the Matlab code but when the code reaches at the Tk[m]
results get a bit different and that causes problem in my code after. I have tried many different ways of converting the code but I get the same different results. What could the problem be?

For your information nmax and N are equal to 128

Matlab Code

```
nmax= 128
N= 128
x = 0:N - 1;
w = 2*x-N+1;
w1= sqrt((N*N-1)/3); 

Tk( 1, : ) = ones( 1, length( x ) )/sqrt(N);
Tk( 2, : ) = (w ./ w1).*Tk( 1, : ); 

    for m = 3:nmax  
        ni=m-1; 
        
        w2_A = N^2-ni^2;
        w2_B = (2*ni+1)*(2*ni-1); 
        w2   = ni*sqrt(w2_A/w2_B);
         
        Tk(m,:) = w./w2.*Tk(m-1,:) - w1/w2*Tk(m-2,:);  
     end
```

Python Code

```
 nmax= 128
 N= 128
 x = np.arange(0, N)
 w = 2*x-N+1
 w1 = np.sqrt((N * N - 1) / 3)

 Tk = np.zeros((nmax, len(x)))

 Tk[1] = np.ones((1, len(x))) / np.sqrt(N)
 Tk[2] = np.multiply(np.divide(w, w1), Tk[1])

    for m in range(3, nmax):
        ni = m-1
        w2_A = N**2 - ni**2 
        w2_B = (2 * ni + 1) * (2 * ni - 1)
        w2 = ni * np.sqrt(w2_A / w2_B)

        Tk[m] = np.multiply(np.divide(w, w2), Tk[m - 1]) - w1 / w2 * Tk[m - 2]
```

Comment: Please define all variables in the code (for example, `N` is undefined) and post valid code (for example, the Matlab loop is missing an `end`) so that the code snippets can be copy-pasted into the command window. Apart from that, Python's `range(3,nmax)` is not equivalent to Matlab's `3:nmax`

Comment: Thanks for your help i fixed some of the mistakes. I mostly cant understand the results in Tk[m]. Since w2_A and w2_B are exactly the same (i have tested it ) how can for example the np.divide(w, w2) give different results than  the w./w2 in matlab?